# General question about making differential equations dimensionless

Tags: fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis, continuum-mechanics, differential-equations, physical-constants

Suppose you have a set of differential equations that you wish to normalize/make dimensionless. From what I've seen, you can usually use dimensional analysis to figure out a good choice of constants to make your variables and parameters dimensionless. However, in fluid dynamics, for example, you also have a few dimensionless quantities at your disposal e.g. Reynolds number, characteristic thermal velocity to flow velocity ratio, etc. How do you figure out how to incorporate these dimensionless quantities into your normalization factors? The goal (I think) is to make your normalized variables and parameters order 1, but I'm confused on how you figure out which dimensionless quantities get the job done.

[Here's a link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/446795/question-about-normalizing-fluid-quantities-plasma-physics) to a different post I made if you want an example of what I'm talking about. It's a little complicated though, and I think this post boils down to what my actual question is.

Any and all insight/help is appreciated, including pointing me to a source which would answer this question.

Comment: There is a straightforward rational method of doing what you want to do.  I won’t go into details here, but you can find what you want in papers by SW Churchill and Hellums and Churchill, circa 1960’s.

Comment: Computation of natural convection by finite difference methods
...... In the process of the nondimensionalization of Eq 3, we advanced the Ozoe and Tagawa approach [5,6]. **We also adopted the Hellums and Churchill method [48]** . As shown in Appendix A, we succeeded in the nondimensionalization of Eq 3. In the bore of a solenoidal subperconducting magnet, we know the magnetic force distributes axisymmetrically. ...